# Slack API: How to change user name of Legacy API token?

Tags: slack, slack-api

When you create a [legacy tokens](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) in slack the name of your token application is always `"Slack API Tester"`:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "bot": {
    "id": "foobar",
    "deleted": false,
    "name": "Slack API Tester",
    "updated": 123456789,
    "app_id": "A123"
  }
}
```

Legacy tokens do not appear in your [applications list](https://api.slack.com/apps) and I am not aware of how to edit any of the info associated with this token.  How can I change the name of the token from `"Slack API Tester"` to something else?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? "Slack API Tester" is just a dummy app name, because there is no Slack app behind it where you would specify a real app name.

Comment: I want to change the name to the email of the root user account the token is associated with to more easily identify who is sending the api requests.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "token application". Token and apps are different concepts on Slack. Are you talking about the name that appears as sender of a message posted with a legacy token?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I want the name of the sender of a message posted with a legacy token to be something other than "Slack API Tester" something my scripts can then use in a `users.lookupByEmail` or `users.info` call.

Comment: I know I can obtain this info with `api.test` but my scripts will not have access to the api token used to send out messages.

Comment: OK. how about capturing all messages through the events API? That will contain the bot_id. Then you should be able to filter out the ones from the legacy token more easily than through email matching. This is the message event: https://api.slack.com/events/message